# Possible to have a SPRibbonPostbackCommand and SPRibbonCommand at the same time?

Tags: javascript, ribbon, postback

I'm happily using `SPRibbonPostBackCommand` to a custom save button. It generates a Postback and everything is fine and dandy.

Previously to generating a Postback I would like to make one Javascript call (e.g. to a function `RemoveAllStatus()`). I tried added an `SPRibbonCommand` prior to the `SPRibbonPostBackCommand`, but now only the `SPRibbonCommand` fires and the postback doesn't fire anymore.

Any ideas? Basically I want to show a "waiting for save" message via Javascript (which of course would be replaced once the page is reloaded after the postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the SPRibbonCommand return false value, thus the post back event does not invoked. To solve this issue you can create you own ribbon component. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407303.aspx) post to understand how to do this.

Comment: The key is to use the `handleCommand` in the custom component.